# Move image with button

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I am currently working on a project that needs to have an image that is moved to each corner of the screen by use of buttons relative to each corner.  The image starts in the top left (northwest) then by clicking the northeast button it moves to the top right etc.  I can't seem to get the image to move even though I confirmed by buttons work by putting alerts in them.  There is text that displays over the image that I will need to move with the image as well, but I am just focusing on getting the image to move at this time.  Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>

    <title> Paragraph over image centered </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <style>
    .container{
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    }


    .text {
    max-width: 20ch;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 210px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         }
    img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
        }

    </style>

<script src="ParagraphOverImageWithButtons.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="container">
    <img id="MyImage" src="MyImage.jpg" alt="MyImage" style="width:25%;">
    <div class="text"> Lines of text Lines of text Lines of text Lines of text 
    Lines of text Lines of text Lines of text Lines of text Lines of text 
    </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="North West" onclick="NWfunction()">
    <input type="button" value="North East" onclick="NEfunction()">
    <input type="button" value="South East" onclick="SEfunction()">
    <input type="button" value="South West" onclick="SWfunction()">


    <a href='http://cis337-0217.cisdprogram.com/Index.html'>
        Return to Index
        </a>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function NWfunction(){
document.getElementById("MyImage").style.top="150px";
document.getElementById("MyImage").style.left="210px";
}

function NEfunction(){
document.getElementById("MyImage").style.top="150px";
document.getElementById("MyImage").style.left="1500px";
}

function SEfunction(){
document.getElementById("MyImage").style.top="1500px";
document.getElementById("MyImage").style.left="1500px";
}

function SWfunction(){
document.getElementById("MyImage").style.top="1500px";
document.getElementById("MyImage").style.left="210px";
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a JS fiddle with a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/dhr6wa2s/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $('#image');
    $('#neast').on('click',function(){
    img.css('right','0');
  });
});
```

change jQuery code as you like for other positions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the direction.  I eventually got to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $('#MyImage');
    $('#NWest').on('click',function(){
    img.css({top: '0px', left: '0px', position:'absolute'});
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('#MyText');
    $('#NWest').on('click',function(){
    text.css({top: '150px', left: '245px', position:'absolute'});
  });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $('#MyImage');
    $('#NEast').on('click',function(){
    img.css({top: '0px', left: '75%', position:'absolute'});
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('#MyText');
    $('#NEast').on('click',function(){
    text.css({top: '150px', left: '88%', position:'absolute'});
  });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $('#MyImage');
    $('#SEast').on('click',function(){
    img.css({top: '560px', left: '75%', position:'absolute'});
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('#MyText');
    $('#SEast').on('click',function(){
    text.css({top: '710px', left: '88%', position:'absolute'});
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $('#MyImage');
    $('#SWest').on('click',function(){
    img.css({top: '560px', left: '0px', position:'absolute'});
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('#MyText');
    $('#SWest').on('click',function(){
    text.css({top: '710px', left: '245px', position:'absolute'});
  });
});
```

Which works great.  But I dont have any experience in jquery since I am still very new to html.  I understand that jquery is a much more up to date way of doing this, but how would I make my original code work.  I want to understand it before passing it over.